# Calculate the midpoint of a polyline

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[image]

I have polylines in a GIS database. The polylines are stored using a user-defined type called [ST_GEOMETRY](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-is-the-st-geometry-storage-type.htm).

ST_GEOMETRY has lots of spatial functions. However, it does not have a polyline **midpoint** function.

Therefore, I have written a custom PL/SQL [midpoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3457843/calculate-the-midpoint-of-a-polyline) function to fill this gap.

As a novice programmer, I'm wondering, how can the code be improved to be as fast and robust as possible?

---

```
-- execute this as the SDE user
create or replace function ST_MidPoint
   (line_in IN sde.st_geometry)
   RETURN sde.st_geometry
IS midpoint sde.st_geometry;
  srid integer;
  line_length number(38);
  num_parts integer;
  num_points integer;
  partNum integer;
  distanceAlong number(38);
  segmentLength number(38);
  part sde.st_geometry;
  p1 sde.st_geometry;
  p2 sde.st_geometry;
  x1 double precision;
  y1 double precision;
  x2 double precision;
  y2 double precision;
BEGIN
  -- get the SRID of the line for later use in constructing the midpoint geometrey
  select sde.st_srid (line_in)
  into srid
  from dual;

  -- calculate the total length of the line
  select sde.st_length(line_in)
  into line_length
  from dual;

  -- get the number of parts that make up the line
  select sde.st_numgeometries(line_in)
  into num_parts
  from dual;

  distanceAlong := 0;
  for partNum in 1..num_parts loop
    --dbms_output.put_line(partNum);
    -- get the geometry for this part
    select sde.st_geometryn(line_in, partNum)
    into part
    from dual;

    -- get the number of points that make up this part
    select sde.st_numpoints(part)
    into num_points
    from dual;
    --dbms_output.put_line(num_points);

    -- get the first point (the "from" point) for the part
    select sde.st_pointn (part, 1)
    into p1
    from dual;

    -- iterate along the line until the section that contains the midpoint is found
    for pointNum in 2..num_points loop
      -- get the "to" point of the segment
      select sde.st_pointn(part, pointNum)
      into p2
      from dual;

      -- calculate the distance between the from point and the to point
      select sde.st_distance(p1, p2)
      into segmentLength
      from dual;

      -- add the distance along this segment to the running total
      distanceAlong := distanceAlong + segmentLength;
      --dbms_output.put_line(distanceAlong);
      -- check to see if the running total is past the midpoint
      if distanceAlong >= line_length/2.0 then
        -- the two current points encompass the midpoint of the line
        -- determine the midpoint geometry and return it
        select sde.st_x(p1)
        into x1
        from dual;
        select sde.st_y(p1)
        into y1
        from dual;
        select sde.st_x(p2)
        into x2
        from dual;
        select sde.st_y(p2)
        into y2
        from dual;
        select sde.st_point((x1+x2)/2.0, (y1+y2)/2.0, srid)
        into midpoint
        from dual;
        -- the midpoint has been found, not need to interogate the rest of the line
        RETURN midpoint;
      end if;
      -- save the endpoint as the first point and continue down the line looking for the midpoint
      p1:=p2;
    end loop;
  end loop;

  return null;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END;
/
grant execute on ST_MidPoint to public;


--select objectid,sde.ST_MidPoint(shape) geom
--from gis.line_test
--order by objectid;
```

**Update:**

I have abandoned this function. It works, but it's horrendously inefficient because it's not possible to use the SDE functions & operators to directly assign values to variables. I needed to wrap them in queries instead.

More information here:
[Use SDE.ST_GEOMETRY functions in a custom function](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344294/use-sde-st-geometry-functions-in-a-custom-function)

Originally, I had thought that the code could be improved. However, now I realize that this is not possible--due to the aforementioned problem.

It would be my preference that this **question be deleted** (I tried but couldn't because there's an answer).

Comment: This is the reason why the INSERT INTOS were used: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/344294/135445

Comment: I think we should close this question. The function is so slow and poorly structured that it's not really useable. I'm going to go with another option (pre-compute with python).

Comment: You can write your own review explaining what makes the function poorly structured. There doesn't seem to be a valid reason to close the question, the other option is that you could delete it yourself.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Yeah, I tried to delete the question, but I couldn't because there's an answer. I also added a note to the question about why the code can't be improved.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to try re-writing the procedure with Buffer and Centroid functions as below.

procedure mindpoint (in_line_geometry)

```
line_buffer_geom = sde.st_buffer (in_line_geometry, 0.05)
cenrtroid_buffer_geom = sde.st_centroid (line_buffer_geom )
return cenrtroid_buffer_geom
```

Comment: (Down-voters please comment.)

Comment: The *cenrtroid* in `cenrtroid_buffer_geom` looks accidental.

Comment: Upon further testing, this doesn't seem to be a good approach. The midpoint doesn't get placed at the correct position along the line (especially curved lines). So, I think a true midpoint calculation would be better (example: a linear referencing solution)

Answer (score 1):

Check this function which returns the mid point X,Y in WKT format. Please note this function uses the SDO_LRS of Oracle which is part of Oracle Spatial.

```
create or replace function get_line_midpoint
   (line_in IN sde.st_geometry)
  -- RETURN sde.st_geometry
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS 
wkt_geometry clob;
ora_geometry sdo_geometry;
mid_x number(10,6);
mid_y number(10,6);
mid_point_geom sde.st_geometry;
BEGIN

SELECT  sde.ST_AsText(line_in) INTO wkt_geometry FROM DUAL;
ora_geometry := SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY(wkt_geometry);

--mid_x:= sdo_cs.transform(SDO_LRS.CONVERT_TO_STD_GEOM(SDO_LRS.LOCATE_PT(SDO_LRS.CONVERT_TO_LRS_GEOM(ora_geometry, 3), SDO_GEOM.SDO_LENGTH(ora_geometry,3)/2)),8307).SDO_POINT.X;
mid_x:= SDO_LRS.CONVERT_TO_STD_GEOM(SDO_LRS.LOCATE_PT(SDO_LRS.CONVERT_TO_LRS_GEOM(ora_geometry, 3), SDO_GEOM.SDO_LENGTH(ora_geometry,3)/2)).SDO_POINT.X;

--mid_y:= sdo_cs.transform(SDO_LRS.CONVERT_TO_STD_GEOM(SDO_LRS.LOCATE_PT(SDO_LRS.CONVERT_TO_LRS_GEOM(ora_geometry, 3), SDO_GEOM.SDO_LENGTH(ora_geometry,3)/2)),8307).SDO_POINT.Y;
mid_y:= SDO_LRS.CONVERT_TO_STD_GEOM(SDO_LRS.LOCATE_PT(SDO_LRS.CONVERT_TO_LRS_GEOM(ora_geometry, 3), SDO_GEOM.SDO_LENGTH(ora_geometry,3)/2)).SDO_POINT.Y;

ora_geometry := SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY('point ('|| mid_x || ' ' || mid_y ||')');



return 'point ('|| mid_x || ' ' || mid_y ||')';




EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: Well, this changes things! [Spatial now free with all editions of Oracle Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclespatial/spatial-now-free-with-all-editions-of-oracle-database).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: The procedure posted works fine. @TobySpeight are you asking the user who posted the question?

Comment: I don't doubt that it works, but that doesn't make it a *code review*.

Comment: I posted a related answer on Stack Overflow: [Get midpoint of SDO.GEOMETRY polyline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59708764/10936066).

Answer (score 0):

To build on @Ashok Vanam's "buffer-and-centroid" idea:

It might be better to use [st_pointonsurface](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-pointonsurface.htm) (point will always be inside polygon) to get the centerpoint of the buffer polygon, instead of [st_centroid](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-centroid.htm) (can fall outside of polygon boundaries):

```
sde.st_x(sde.st_pointonsurface(sde.st_buffer(shape, 0.05))) as x,
sde.st_y(sde.st_pointonsurface(sde.st_buffer(shape, 0.05))) as y
```

> ST_PointOnSurface takes an ST_Polygon or ST_MultiPolygon and returns
> an ST_Point **guaranteed to lie on its surface**.

> ST_Centroid takes a polygon, multipolygon, or multilinestring and
> returns the point that is in the **center of the geometry's envelope**.
> That means that the centroid point is halfway between the geometry's
> minimum and maximum x and y extents.

It's not the classiest solution in the world. But on the plus side, it is very simple/concise.

Comment: Upon further testing, this doesn't seem to be a good approach. The midpoint doesn't get placed at the correct position along the line (especially curved lines). So, I think a true midpoint calculation would be better (example: a linear referencing solution)